# Visual Studio ClickOnce deployment fails on Windows 7

Tags: winforms, deployment, clickonce

I have a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application that I am using ClickOnce deployment for and everything publishes fine when I am attempting to publish in Windows XP. When I try the same publish feature in Windows 7, it hangs on the publish step.

I am using a [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path (file share) to the server ([Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 with [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) 7). Why might this happen?

I never receive an error message and the process cannot be cancelled. I have to force-close Visual Studio and restart my Windows 7 PC because Visual Studio has some of the files locked.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to set full-control permission on the folder on the destination server for my domain PC, and I was then able to publish *once*. Then, every subsequent deploy hanged. I did notice however that it always hangs when it's trying to copy the Office Interop files. Why would this be?

**UPDATE (2):**

This is definitely related to the Office 2010 PIA files. Why would it not publish them? Again, this works flawlessly on Windows XP, but when I perform the deployment on Windows 7, the PIAs are not published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) issue. Try running Visual Studio as an administrator when you do a publish.

Comment: It was semi-related to UAC.  It was a network-related issue where it was being blocked.  I have since resolved the issue and will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @Keith - Doesn't sound like it was UAC then, you should answer your own question with the steps you took and mark that as the answer.